# How to use gnu_parallel to run multiple executable and/or bash scripts?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I've been recently attempting to run my scripts in parallel in a more convenient way than to open a several instances of terminal and executing in scripts separately.

I've been trying to learn how to use gnu_parallel for the past couple of days and I am still a bit clueless, and hoping if someone can provide a direct example.

Suppose I have a g++ compiled code called blah.exe and a bash script called blah.sh that will run alone perfectly fine, but I want to execute them in different directories.

I've been reading
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Working-as-xargs--n1.-Argument-appending

and

https://www.biostars.org/p/182136/

but I am not totally clear about the syntax

To run these in series, I would do:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
mv ./blah.exe directory$i
cd directory$i
./blah.exe all
cd ..
end
```

similarly

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
mv ./blah.sh directory$i
cd directory$i
source ./blah.sh all
cd ..
end
```

I am trying to under stand how I would split this load to 4 logical-threads in one command using parallel.

Could someone provide an example for this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: does your script affect any shared ressource that could make the parallelization somehow harder ?

Comment: If you want to run a process in the background in `bash`, then append `&` to the command. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)

Comment: Jesper, yes I can use bash and &, but I want to write a single script to parallelize using gno_parallel

Comment: Reda, as far as I know, I carefully mallocated and won't be extra hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
parallel --dry-run 'cd directory{}; ../blah.exe all; source ../blah.sh all' ::: {1..4}
```

No need to copy/move the executable, just run the same one.

No need to `cd ..` afterwards, as it's a new process each time.

Note this is not multi-threading, it is multi-processing.

---

If you want to process **discontiguous** directory numbers, you can use:

```
parallel ... ::: {1..4} 6 7 {11..14}
```

If you want to process **all** directories, you can use:

```
printf "%s\0" */ | parallel -0 'cd {}; pwd'
```

If you want to process **all directories starting with `FRED`**, you can use:

```
printf "%s\0" FRED*/ | parallel -0 'cd {}; pwd'
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. You are right, this is multi-processing, sorry for the misclassification, I will change that. This is pretty much it. I only have one more questions for you:

First, say if I wanted to do 
1..4 then 6, the 11..20, what would be the proper syntax? I tried running with 1,2,3,4,6, ...

Another is is there an option to print the printouts and logs?

Comment: I have added an example of the syntax for discontiguous directory numbers. Can you clarify or question about the logs and printouts please? Which logs and printouts? Where are they?

Comment: Regarding the log, please nevermind. It got saved in the cache somehow, from testing I found a way to just use "command >log.log"

Comment: However, I think this may be against the policy of one topic per question but I have even one more question. Suppose that I have a huge list of files that I need to execute "blah.exe" on.

Say I have the file name list in "glah.tmp"
I know to use while command <<glah.tmp
is there a gnu_parallel equivalent to this?

Comment: Questions are free - and answers! I think it might be better to ask another one as there are potentially several solutions and it could get messy. You can always click `share` under your original question and copy the hyperlink and paste it into the new question for reference. I'll keep an eye out for a new question, and I am sure Ole Tange (the author of `parallel`) will see it too, so you should get a response quite soon.